# old kernels cannot be removed in Synaptic?

Tags: kernel

I'm running MATE 16.04 on an ASUS X550LA, when I run:

```
$ ls /boot | grep vmlinuz | cut -d'-' -f2,3
4.13.0-38
4.13.0-38
4.13.0-39
4.13.0-39
```

(I have ran `sudo apt-get autoremove` before)
Yet when I run Synaptic package manager with "linux-image-4*" in the search I see a large amounts of what I believe to be old kernels.
[image]

This is only a part of the read out, and almost all except the current kernel show a white square, and properties of any selected show "not installed". If I select any of these and right click I am offered "Mark for installation" or "Properties"

What are these? Can they be safely removed? How do I remove them?

Comment: The white square indicates that it is *not* installed but available to install if you wish. Further down, you may see green squares. That indicates packages that *are* installed.

Comment: @chili555 is right. If they were installed at one time, you have *already* removed them.  The list you are looking at is NOT a list of what-is-installed. It is a list of what-is-available in the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: I appreciate the answers, I feel I understand the significance of the "white/green" indicators. Thank you both.